# Does anyone has a working smart tag solution for autolinking bug numbers from emails?

Tags: email, outlook, hyperlink, smart-tags

I'm looking for a solution that will auto add hyper-links to Outlooks emails (including incoming) when the email does contain a text like "bug # 1234" or similar.

There are some information on this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa159903(office.11).aspx) but I wasn't able to find any working solution so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I havent done it before but may be this is a good pointer it would only seem possible if word is used.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178786.aspx#smarttagsdk
Also there is an active news group

http://groups.google.co.uk/group/microsoft.public.office.developer.smarttags/browse_thread/thread/4c2c6c177133759f/?pli=1